# What really happened to Michael's mother?

Tags: plot-explanation, prison-break

It was clear by watching the first season of [*Prison Break*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0455275/) that Michael's mother died when she was 31. And Michael was also having the same disease. But in season 4 she came into the show. How was she still alive?

Comment: I think in season 4 they consulted M. Night Shymalan...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She was never dead, she worked for "The Company" an organization in the show that made her leave her family behind.